# Array of objects returned in subscription cannot be assigned to another array

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe, subscriber

I'm trying to assign the returned array from the server in withing the subscribe method. The problem I'm facing is that after I assign the array it shows as undefined if I console log it. However, if I console log it inside the subscription method it shows all elements.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Here is my code:

```
export class GetMoviesComponent implements OnInit {

  movies: Movie[];
  constructor(private movieService: MovieServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe((data: Movie[])
      => {
      this.movies = data;

    });

    this.lol();
  }
  lol() {
    console.log(this.movies);
  }

}
```

And below is my service that calls the API

```
getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.baseUrl + 'getmovies');
}
```

Comment: Of course it's undefined. You call lol() immediately after you've sent the request. If you want to print the response, you need to print it when it's received, i.e. from **inside** the subscribe callback.

Comment: Could you please show how the data coming from the server would be assigned to that array created in the component and used in the HTML?

Comment: You already assign the data correctly. You can see it if you call `this.lol()` just after assigning the data. In your code, you call it outside of the callback.